# rsa encryption using mod function linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, math, rsa

Using the bash shell I am trying to compute 78390^91025(mod 180577) 
So using the base 78290 the power of 910025 and applying the modulus of 180577, I wish to obtain the following logic: 
`y=base` for `i = 1` to the exponent-1 `y := (y*base) mod 'modulus' next i print y`

In doing this I hope to save memory and storage while still obtaining the correct result.

```
#!/bin/bash
# encrypt RSA script
base=78390                  # base number for operations
power=91025                     
               # reads input 'power' from the user   command line
modulus=180577                  # relative prime number to find remainders
y=base                          # place holder for next iteration

if [ -f "encrypt.txt" ]; then   # if this file exists then remove it
rm encrypt.txt
fi
i=0                             # initialize the variable i
while IFS= read -r -n1 char
do 
printf -v num %d "'$char"   # assigns a numerical value to characters
if [ $num != 0 ]; then
   let "num = num - 97"
   ((i++))
   let "keys[i]=num"
fi
done < "$base"              # pulls the value of base from storage
let "ilength = i"
echo length of base $ilength

i=0                             # initialize counter variable
while IFS= read -r -n1 char
do

#   Convert characters to ASCII equivalent   numbers
printf -v num %d "'$char"
if [[ $num != 0 ]] && [[ $num != 32 ]]; then
    ((i++))                 # increments the value of i; the counter
let "im1=i-1"
let "imod=im1%ilength"
let "ii=imod+1"
let "base=keys[ii]"
let "num=num-97"            # Reset ASCII value to begin at 0
let "num=num*$base"         # Multiply by base
let "num=num % modulus"     # Apply modulus
let "num=num+97"            # Return to ASCII value
                            # Convert ASCII numbers to characters
printf -v newchar \\$(printf '%03o' "$num")
    echo $newchar >> output.txt
fi
if [ $num = 32 ]; then
   echo $char >> output.txt # prints the value of char to file
fi
if [ $num = 0 ]; then
    echo '@' >> output.txt  
# prints location of error to file respective to line which error 
occurred 
fi

done < "$INPUT"
cat output.txt | tr '\n' Z | sed 's/ZZ/ /g' | sed 's/Z//g' | 
sed 's/@/\n/g' > encrypt.txt
rm output.txt                   
# Stores output in file names "encrypt" and erases temporary file 
"output.txt"
```

Thanks this is what I have so far I know the `^-1` is missing and I do not think I am storing `y` correctly.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  When I run your script on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, it produces the following errors.  Please edit your script to run without errors or ask for help removing a specific error:

> $ bash rsa.sh
> rsa.sh: line 21: 78390: No such file or directory
> length of base 0
> rsa.sh: line 54: : No such file or directory
> cat: output.txt: No such file or directory
> rsa.sh: line 59: output.txt: command not found

Comment: Do you know about the separate utility `bc` . Not sure about your use case, but generally things like `echo "(78390^91025)%180577" | bc` should work.